# Nvidia No devices were found Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, cuda

Lately i have installed `cuda toolkit dev conda` and my system is reporting `No devices were found` when i check `nvidia-smi`

I have  checked nvidia tools in my systems

```
lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_uvm           1011712  0
nvidia_drm             53248  0
nvidia_modeset       1228800  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              34156544  2 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        217088  2 amdgpu,nvidia_drm
nvidiafb               53248  0
vgastate               20480  1 nvidiafb
fb_ddc                 16384  1 nvidiafb
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 nvidiafb,amdgpu
drm                   552960  12 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,nvidia_drm,ttm
```

and also ubuntu drivers

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
[sudo] password for dev: 
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001F99sv000017AAsd00003A43bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-driver-460-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - third-party non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-465 - third-party non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

I don't know what should i do in order to run my GPU

Answer (score 0):

Particular version of CUDA is fully compatible with specific versions of Driver, which is kind of a nightmare. However nvidia-smi is part of the driver, not CUDA. It's hard to see how installing CUDA can screw it up. I would uninstall whatever you installed and see what happens.

Comment: No ,change . I am still facing the same problem